# Merging country-year data with event-based data

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I'm trying to merge two datasets in R. I normally use `dplyr` to merge two country-year based data sets. But in this case:

`dataset1` is `country-year`:

[image: start of dataset1]

`dataset2` is event-based: imagine something like big terror attacks. The events don't happen every year. In some years, there is more than one event.

[image: start of dataset2]

Ideal outcome: integrate `dataset2` into the `country-year` format and have a count for the total number of events that year. How would this work?

Comment: Please provide some example data. It is not possible to help without understanding the structure of your data. Hopefully, your event data includes year and country variables.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Point taken. I added photos of the datasets where you can see the relevant variables to merge. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each row in your `dataset2` represents a single event, this should do what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

dataset2 %>%
    group_by(location, year) %>%
    summarize(n_events = n()) %>%
    left_join(dataset1, ., by = c("cname" = "location", "year" = "year"))
```

Comment: In this code, what would be after 

summarize(n_events = n()) %>%

the n here? Also, what does the "." refer to after dataset1 in the left_join function?

left_join(dataset1, ., by = c("cname" = "location", "year" = "year"))